# Base table or view not found after upgrading to a higher laravel 7 version

Tags: laravel

I've updated my laravel, re-ran my migrations and the app crashed.

The error I'm getting is: `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homewrk.homework'`

But, please take a look at this:

It is telling me the problem is here:

```
$results = Subject::with(['user'])->where('user_id', $user_id)->withCount('homeworks');
$subjects = $results->latest()->get();
```

But, as you can see, I'm trying to get `homeworks` here:

`$results = Subject::with(['user'])->where('user_id', $user_id)->withCount('homeworks');`

I really cannot understand what's going on.

I just updated, got the error, rolled back migrations, then did `php artisan migrate`

finally, I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

apparently, Laravel no longers knows automatically which table it should look for. I made it work specifying the table in the model using:

`public $table = "homeworks";`